# in-app billing for unsupported countries

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, credit-card, in-app-billing

I want to use Google Play's in-app billing for one of my applications. But it seems I can't use it.

**First problem** is that according to [supported locations for merchants](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324) my country - Turkey - is not in the list.

**And as a second problem**, my app is listed on some other markets except Google Play. [Google Play in-app billing overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) section **In-app Billing Requirements and Limitations** says that *In-app billing can be implemented only in applications that you publish through Google Play.* Therefore even if Turkey will be in merchant list in the future, I could not use Google Play's in-app billing for other markets. Is that right?

Then I thought using other APIs like [ZooZ](http://www.zooz.com/), [Authorize.net](http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/) (Actually, I did not examine them deeply, but I guess they do what I want)

But this time I read in [Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html) that *All fees received by Developers for Products distributed via the Market must be processed by the Market's Payment Processor.* Is that a problem for using such APIs? If so, what should I do for in-app purchase?

Answer (score 3):

If your country is not supported, you can't really use In-App billing for your app. You could look at alternate stores, for example, Amazon app store. they have recently implemented In-App billing.

https://developer.amazon.com/welcome.html

The simple answer for Google Play would be "No" for now, till Google supports Turkey.

Answer (score 1):

Get a bank account in a country that does support merchant accounts.

Comment: Is that the only thing google is asking for? Don't they additionally ask for a proof of address in that country? Or something else that might be hard to achieve.

Comment: You know I haven't done it myself. A friend of mine said he looked into this and that it is not a terribly difficult task.