# In App Billing for not supported country

Tags: google-play-services

I am living in country which is not supported for Google play merchant. So, Can I implement In App Billing in my game and upload to the play store? Do so player can purchase or not? If can how about purchased report can I see or not?

Appreciated for your kindly help.

Best Regards,
Virak

Comment: AFAIK, most countries are already supported to download free apps and only few is not supported for paid apps. See this [list](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3541286) of supported locations for distributions to Google Play users. With this, you can administer in-app billing wherein you can specify target countries for your app. More information on how to work with order number when user purchases can also be found in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html).

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119961/in-app-billing-for-unsupported-countries) might also help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity IAP in a country where I can't register as merchant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863434/unity-iap-in-a-country-where-i-cant-register-as-merchant)